# Understanding pytest-django test arguments

Tags: python, django, pytest, pytest-django, pytest-mock

What are '**rf**' and '**user_context**' parameters and when are they assigned?

```py
import pytest
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.reverse import reverse

from request_helper import pytest_request


@pytest.mark.urls(urls='api.urls')
@pytest.mark.django_db
def test_user_name_check_200(rf, users_context):
    data = {
        'username': 'test_jay_2'
    }
    url = reverse(viewname="users-check")
    response = pytest_request(rf,
                              method='get',
                              url=url,
                              user=None,
                              data=data)

    assert response.status_code == status.HTTP_200_OK
```

Comment: from where did you copy this snippet code? have your access to request_helper module?

Answer (score 1):

Both are `pytest` fixtures (read about fixtures here: [About fixtures](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/explanation/fixtures.html)). `rf` is defined in `pytest-django` ([reference](https://pytest-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/helpers.html#rf-requestfactory)); a `RequestFactory` instance will be automatically injected for the `rf` argument in test. `users_context` is a fixture defined somewhere in your test project; search for something like

```
@pytest.fixture
def users_context():
    ...
```

in project code.